# laravel nova BelongsTo relation clear not allowed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I have a BelongsTo laravel nova field with nullable values allowed and searchable but when I click on x to remove field value and save resource, again I have old value stored so its imposible to remove

```
BelongsTo::make('Empresa')
                    ->prepopulate()
                    ->sortable()
                    ->searchable()
                    ->nullable()
                ,
```

Comment: remove prepopulate() and try it

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check your policies. Maybe some your policy disallow to show Empresa model.